# Chrome extension: sending a request form a background page to the popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make the background page communicate with the popup in a google chrome extension.

I managed to make it work the other way around, but for some reason it doesn't work now.

```
// background.html
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {
            method: 'countDown',
            seconds: seconds,
            id: id
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });
    });

// popup.html
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log('request from background');

        if(request.method == 'countDown') {
            console.log(request.seconds);

            //countDown(request.id);
        }

        sendResponse({});
    });
```

The permissions are right (background, tabs), but it seems like the background is not sending out the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code executes [`chrome.tabs.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/tabs.html#method-sendRequest), which is used to communicate with a content script that's been injected into a tab. If you'd like to communicate with your extension's popup, use [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/extension.html#method-sendRequest) instead.

Comment: Wow, that works. Not sure why I was using chrome.tabs, maybe the documentation was a little confusing http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: Can you file a request at http://new.crbug.com/ noting the confusion? If there's something simple we can add to that page that would make this use-case clear, I'm happy to do it.

Comment: It's probably not really confusing, I just misinterpreted the documentation.

Comment: Ok. If you do have suggestions, do let me know.